# React-Native - PushNotificationIOS - Click on Push does not render the App

Tags: react-native, push

I have a strange behavior with push notifications.
To explain:

A message is sent to the user with the "PushNotificationsIOS" library. (This is sent when the app is in the background and completely closed about a certain GPS action).
If the user now clicks on the push notification, the app is opened, but nothing more. It looks as if a kind of "cache" version is displayed.
Neither componentDidMount, render() etc. is called. This is of course very stupid, as actions such as fetch etc. are executed on a specific page.
Does anyone have an idea why this behavior occurs?
To summarize: Clicking on a push opens the app but is not rendered.

I use the following versions:

- "react": "18.2.0"
- "react-native": "0.71.7"
- "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.11.0"

I send notifications like

```html
PushNotificationIOS.addNotificationRequest({
    id: 'test',
    body: 'test',
    title: 'test'
});
```

Comment: After I upgraded to Xcode 13.1 and made a release build, the problem was fixed.

Comment: I actually use xcode 15.1. I try to update again and build release again

Comment: I updated to xcode 15.2, but the bug is always there :)